# Stacked Column combined with Line

Tags: sapui5

We need to display a stacked column chart combined with a line chart and would like to stick to the VizFrame control offered by UI5. Is there a way to achieve this? It's not listed in the samples (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame/samples) but maybe there is a way to do it anyway.

**EDIT**

The data we need to display comes in the following format:

```
var data = [
    {week: 1, stacked1: 10, stacked2: 20, stacked3: 30, line: 100},
    {week: 2, stacked1: 12, stacked2: 13, stacked3: 14, line: 40},
    {week: 3, stacked1: 14, stacked2: 25, stacked3: 26, line: 20},
    {week: 4, stacked1: 15, stacked2: 24, stacked3: 33, line: 52}
];
```

So the idea is to have weeks on the x-axis, a stacked bar for the values stacked1, stacked2 and stacked3 as well as a value point for the line.

Comment: What do you mean by "combined"? Overlayed?

Comment: Like https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.CombinedColumnLine/preview. Having stacked columns and a line at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use setVizType("stacked_combination") [or vizType: "stacked_combination"] on the VizFrame. You can see all the type on the getVizType() VizFrame doumentation. Here is a simple example where I extended the VizFrame and added two functions to display a Line Stacked Column Chart:

```
sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame.extend("jonova.ui5.chart.JuVizFrame", {
  renderer: { },

  setLineStackedBar: function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(
            [{Product:"Total",  Date: 2000, Available: 100},
             {Product:"Total",  Date: 2001, Available: 100},
             {Product:"P1",         Date: 2000, Utilized:  30},
             {Product:"P1",         Date: 2001, Utilized:  20},
             {Product:"P2",         Date: 2000, Utilized:  40},
             {Product:"P2",         Date: 2001, Utilized:  60}]);
    var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [{name: 'Date',      value: '{Date}'},
                     {name: 'Product',   value: '{Product}'}],
        measures:   [{name: 'Available', value: '{Available}'},
                     {name: 'Utilized',  value: '{Utilized}' }],
        data:        {path: "/"}});
    var oFeeds = [new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({uid: "valueAxis",    type: "Measure",   values: ["Utilized", "Available"]}),
                  new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({uid: "categoryAxis", type: "Dimension", values: ["Date"]}),
                  new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({uid: "color",        type: "Dimension", values: ["Product"]})];
    this.setChart("stacked_combination", oDataset, oModel, oFeeds);
  },

  setChart: function(aVizType, aDataset, aModel, aFeeds) {
    this.setVizType(aVizType);
    this.setDataset(aDataset);
    this.setModel(aModel);
    for( var i=0, len=aFeeds.length; i<len; i++) this.addFeed(aFeeds[i]);
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the data we need to display comes in a different format. I updated my question. Maybe you know how to handle that as well.